# JavaScript Array Comparison Function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, comparison

I currently have a `map` of an array of users which all have a unique `_id` key / value.

`user = [{_id: "1", ... }, {_id: "2", ... }, ... ]`

I also have two other arrays, one named `teams` and another named `accounts`.

`teams = [{ _id: "1", members: [{ userId: "2" }, { userId: "4" }, ... ], ... }]`

`accounts = [{ _id: "1", authorizedUsers: [{ userId: "3"}, ... ], ownerTeamId: "2" }, ... ]`

Trying to create two comparison functions which takes the argument of `user` and outputs `numberOfTeams` and `numberOfAccounts` for the corresponding `user`.

I have attempted the `numberOfTeams` below but I'm not sure if it's the most optimal.

```
numberOfTeams(user) {
  let count = 0;
  teams.forEach(team => {
    team.members.forEach(member => {
      if (member.userId === user._id) {
        count++
      }
    })
  });
  return count;
}
```

With the `numberOfAccounts`, I'm stuck on how to compare `authorizedUsers === user._id` **OR** `ownerTeamId === team._id` where also `members.userId === user.id`, and then `count++`.

Comment: `numberOfAccounts` property does not appear at `javascript` objects at Question? What is `numberOfAccounts` referencing, `members` array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s probably a good start to write a function to get the teams a user belongs to:

```
function containsUserId(users, id) {
    return users.some(user => user.userId === id);
}

function getUserTeams(user, teams) {
    return teams.filter(team =>
        containsUserId(team.members, user._id));
}
```

because then you can write `numberOfTeams` using it:

```
numberOfTeams(user) {
    return getUserTeams(user, teams).length;
}
```

then a similar function to get accounts:

```
function getUserAccounts(user, accounts) {
    const userTeamIds = new Set(
        getUserTeams(user).map(team => team._id)
    );

    return accounts.filter(account =>
        containsUserId(account.authorizedUsers, user._id) ||
        userTeamIds.has(accounts.ownerTeamId));
}
```

then `numberOfAccounts` using it:

```
numberOfAccounts(user) {
    return getUserAccounts(user, accounts).length;
}
```

Essentially: use more functions so you can understand the steps you’re taking to solve your own problem and, in doing so, use those steps more effectively.